# Remove special characters and substrings from strings in column

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I am fairly new to all of this. I am using Python and the pandas library to work with a large dataset that looks like this e.g.:

```
           date                              text
0   Jul 31 2020       "test sentence numerouno"
1   Jul 31 2020       (second sentence) unonumero
2   Jul 31 2020       testuno sentence!!!
```

Now I am looking for a function/loop which removes a defined set of substring as well as special characters.

So to be specific and stick to the example, I want to remove all the special characters `"` `(` `)` `!` as well as the substring `uno` from the column 'text'.

So the output should look like this:

```
           date                         text
0   Jul 31 2020       test sentence numero
1   Jul 31 2020       second sentence numero
2   Jul 31 2020       test sentence
```

Appreciate the help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with the following pattern:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'[^ A-Za-z]+|uno','')

print(df.text)
0      test sentence numero
1    second sentence numero
2             test sentence
Name: text, dtype: object
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzF3xL/1)

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks a lot!